# Updating .Net Maui ListView

Tags: c#, maui

I am having trouble updating my ListView in .Net Maui. I am using the below code to Remove the initial value and Insert the updated value. And its strange that it will only update the first item in the ListView fine, but will not work with any other items. Greatly appreciate any help !

```
Userdefinedfields.RemoveAt(idx);
Userdefinedfields.Insert(idx, tmp);
```

Comment: please take the time to format any code that you post so it is readable.  And include enough relevant context - in this case knowing the type of `Userdefinedfields` would be very useful

Comment: The code you show is fine; therefore it is something about how it is used. (Or as Jason suggests, somehow related to the type of Userdefinedfields.) Or its a Maui bug, but its unclear what the bug is, without seeing more code. Did you try replacing 2nd item WITHOUT first replacing 1st item? Is tmp different than the value you are replacing? In your test, is the replace happening on some user action (button push)?

Comment: Yes, I tried to replace second item. Yes, tmp is the updated value. Yes, the update is happening when user clicks the OK button.

Comment: You’ve had two requests for more info on the type - is there a reason you’re not sharing that?

Comment: Its a generic type

Comment: Its a Generic Type of Strings and Integers

Comment: Is it a List?  An ObservableCollection?  Or something else?  We’re trying to help you yet you’re being evasive about answering basic questions

Comment: ObservableCollection. Why do you accuse me of being evasive, I am stumped on trying to figure out what he problem is.  What other platforms do very easily it seems like its climbing Mount Everest with Maui. Lots of moving parts for sure.

Comment: Because it should not take repeated requests for you to answer a simple question.  Please read [ask] before posting

Comment: If it's an ObservableCollection, shouldn't you just call `SetItem` ?

Comment: @JSmith: This is a puzzling bug, and a lot more information is needed, to help you. ***Please add to question the following:*** 1)  the line(s) where Userdefinedfields is declared. That might be something like `public List<string> Userdefinedfields;`. 2) The complete XAML of the ListView. 3) The complete c# of the method that includes the two lines you show in question. 4) The c# of the method that filled Userdefinedfields with values. 5) Re *'I tried to replace second item."* - Show the code that decided which item to replace. I need to understand how you tested replacing the second item.

Comment: 6) Re *"the update is happening when user clicks the OK button"* - is that button on the same page as the ListView? Is there some control in which the user typed or selected which item to replace?  And there is another control in which user typed a new string?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I am using a syncfusion listview countrol so that I can have something resembling Cards in 2 columns. So, to do that I had to set SpanCount="2" in the syncfusion listview and this is why the listview is not updating because when I removed Spancount=2 and only had a single column the ListView began updating correctly. In other words the problem was in my layout or Xaml. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated concerning another way to have a two column card view layout that updates.

Comment: Can you provide the code about your layout and some necessary code behind?